# Importing multiple excel files into Python, merge and apply filename to a new column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

I have a for loop that imports all of the Excel files in the directory and merge them together in a single dataframe. However, I want to create a new column where each row takes the string of the filename of the Excel-file.

Here is my import and merge code:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1', header = None, names = ['col1','col2'])
    df = df.append(data)
```

For example if first Excel file is named "file1.xlsx", I want all rows from that file to have value `file1.xlsx` in `col3` (a new column). If the second Excel file is named "file2.xlsx" I want all rows from that file to have value `file2.xlsx`. Notice that there is no real pattern of the Excel files, and I just use those names as an example.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new column in loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1', header = None, names = ['col1','col2'])
    data['col3'] = f
    df = df.append(data)
```

Another possible solution with list comprehension:

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1', header = None, names = ['col1','col2']).assign(col3 = f)
        for f in files]

 df = pd.concat(dfs)
```